# Multiple Column Filtering With BindingListView

Tags: .net, search, datagridview, filtering, bindinglist

I am using the BindingListView dll located at http://blw.sourceforge.net/ to enable sorting of a DataGridView with a Generic List as it's DataSource. I read about filtering and it is fairly simple to use but I'm having issues trying to figure out how to use multiple search parameters for the filter. Here is an example...

```
Private Sub txtProjectNumber_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtProjectNumber.TextChanged, txtDescription.TextChanged,
    txtOracleNumber.TextChanged, txtBudgetYearFrom.TextChanged, txtBudgetYearTo.TextChanged, txtWeek3Start.TextChanged, txtWeek3End.TextChanged
    view.ApplyFilter(AddressOf FilterData)
End Sub

Private Function FilterData(ByVal projectDetails As ProjectDetails) As Boolean
    Try
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtProjectNumber.Text) Then  
            Return projectDetails.ProjectNum.ToLower().StartsWith(txtProjectNumber.Text.ToLower())
        End If
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDescription.Text) Then
            Return projectDetails.Description.ToLower().StartsWith(txtDescription.Text.ToLower())
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

So here you can see that if I change the text in the txtProjectNumber TextBox my filter will return the correct results. But if I say put, "x" in the txtProjectNumber TextBox and want to also search by txtDescription of "morning", the txtDescription is ignored because it hits the txtProjectNumber and is returned, never hitting the txtDescription TextBox. How can I get it to continue all the way down, building a filter from each non-empty input?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to return a boolean based on the test, you are not actually returning the object itself so rather than the multiple returns simply put your conditions in an if/andalso statement and return true if all your conditions are met.

```
Private Function FilterData(ByVal projectDetails As ProjectDetails) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False

    If projectDetails.ProjectNum.ToLower().StartsWith(txtProjectNumber.Text.ToLower()) andalso _
       projectDetails.Description.ToLower().StartsWith(txtDescription.Text.ToLower()) andalso _

              <remaining tests>

       result = true
    End If
Return result
End Function
```